# I want to spin icon into it's old state when click it again

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, icons

I want to spin the icons in to it's old state when click on the icons again without losing current features.
current features:

1. icon will rotate 180 degree on first click on corresponding icon.
2. icon will rotate back on click  either on  other icon or outside.

with this features I want to add a new feature ,ie, the icon need to be spin back when we click it again.

```js
function rotate(e){
  resetRotation();
  document.getElementById("me").className="spinner in fa fa-caret-down";
  e.stopPropagation();
}

function resetRotation(){
  document.getElementById("me").className="spinner out fa fa-caret-down";
  document.getElementById("you").className="spinner out fa fa-caret-down";
}

function rotatea(e){
  resetRotation();
  document.getElementById("you").className="spinner in fa fa-caret-down";
  e.stopPropagation();
}

document.addEventListener('click', resetRotation);
```

```css
.spinner {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.spinner.in{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.spinner.out{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i onclick="rotate(event)" id="me" class="spinner fa fa-caret-down "></i>
<i onclick="rotatea(event)" id="you" class="spinner fa fa-caret-down"></i>
```

Comment: You should change the class again after you rotated it and then if you click it again use the new class to rotate it back

Comment: yep...it may work

Comment: but.. where  i will give the new assignment..,i'm confused about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you already added the ***in*** class to your ***i tag*** to rotate back and exit the function. To check element already has a class use the following code,

```
document.querySelector("#you").classList.contains("in")
```

```js
function rotate(e) {
  // Check is already rotated and return
  if (document.querySelector("#me").classList.contains("in")) {
    resetRotation();
    return;
  }
  resetRotation();
  document.getElementById("me").className = "spinner in fa fa-caret-down";
  e.stopPropagation();
}

function resetRotation() {
  document.getElementById("me").className = "spinner out fa fa-caret-down";
  document.getElementById("you").className = "spinner out fa fa-caret-down";
}

function rotatea(e) {
  // Check is already rotated and return
  if (document.querySelector("#you").classList.contains("in")) {
    resetRotation();
    return;
  }
  resetRotation();
  document.getElementById("you").className = "spinner in fa fa-caret-down";
  e.stopPropagation();
}

document.addEventListener('click', resetRotation);
```

```css
.spinner {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.spinner.in {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.spinner.out {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div style="padding:20px;">
  <i onclick="rotate(event)" id="me" class="spinner fa fa-caret-down "></i>
  <i onclick="rotatea(event)" id="you" class="spinner fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var isChanged=true
    function rotate(e){

      document.getElementById("me").className="spinner fa fa-caret-down"+ (isChanged?"in":"out");

      isChanged=!isChanged;

      e.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Similarly you can do for rotatea